# MySql Error 1064 - Created using MySQL WorkBench

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, create-table

I created this using MySQL WorkBench

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bakasura_new`.`cities` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'City Name' ,
  `short_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Short Name' ,
  `country_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_cities_countries` (`country_id` ASC) ,
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I am getting this error

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #### #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>
> corresponds to your MySQL server
> version for the right syntax to use
> near '= InnoDB' at line 8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a dangling comma here:

```
INDEX `fk_cities_countries` (`country_id` ASC) ,
```

And you also have a missing parenthesis at the end:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bakasura_new`.`cities` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'City Name' ,
  `short_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Short Name' ,
  `country_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_cities_countries` (`country_id` ASC)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: @Harsha M V: Just tried it myself, and it worked. Note that I removed a comma and added a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `)` missing at the end of the last `)`

```
INDEX `fk_cities_countries` (`country_id` ASC) )
```

Comment: thank you. works now :D  Mysql Workbench had created Constraints which i wanted to remove. guess i deleted the bracket bymistake. any idea how to export from mysql Workbench with out constraints

Comment: @Harsha: What type of constraints did Workbench create? Can you give an example?

Comment: CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `areas` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `slug` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `zipcode` INT(11) NULL ,
  `latitude` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `longitude` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  `city_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_areas_cities1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`city_id` )
    REFERENCES `cities` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_areas_cities1` ON `areas` (`city_id` ASC) ;

Comment: @Harsha: It looks like you want to remove the foreign key on `city_id`. I think you can remove the foreign key from the EER diagram: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-relationship-tools.html. Just delete the link. By removing that constraint manually, you were effectively removing the constraint on the link.

Comment: but i want the linking between the two tables. otherwise i am not able to link them right ?

Comment: @Harsha: You will still be able to "link" the tables in your queries using JOINs, even if there is no foreign key constraint. Try it out.

Comment: @Daniel guess it only helps the EER diagram :D